# Shared folder in ASP.NET MVC 4 project is hidden

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, directory

For some reason, my shared folder ,which contains some error pages and my master `_layout.cshtml` page, is hidden. I can only access it when I click on show all files in my solution explorer. This is not a real problem, everything still works but I know this is not standard.

I don't know how this folder became a hidden folder, but does anyone know how to set the folder visible?

When I browse to my project folder in my file system, the folder is not a hidden folder...
I use **Visual studio 2012**, os = **windows 7 64 bit**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a wild guess here, but can you right click it (in Visual Studio) and "Include In Project"?

Comment: need to wait some minutes :) hold on

Comment: just read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85521/why-does-stackoverflow-make-you-wait-2-x-minutes-before-you-can-accept-an-answer), fair enough :) my bad

Comment: Note that it may be necessary to first click the "Show All Files" button at the top right of the solution explorer menu bar. This shows the excluded files/folder.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be included in your `.csproj` file.

To include it, either open your `.csproj` file in notepad and add in the lines or remove the folder from the project and add it back in.